# Firebird and dummy conditions

Tags: firebird

I have two, similar queries. In one of case have additional dummy where conditions (1=1, 0=0, true):

```sql
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.fk_t1 = t1.id
JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.id = t1.fk_t3
WHERE
    0 = 0 AND /* with this in 1st case, without this line in 2nd case */
    t3.field = 6
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2 x WHERE x.fk2_t2 = t2.id)
```

All necessary fields are indexed.

For each case, Firebird (both versions 2.1 and 3.0) works differently, and statistics of reads see like this:

1st case (with 0=0):

```
Query Time
------------------------------------------------
Prepare       : 32,00 ms
Execute       : 1 046,00 ms
Avg fetch time: 61,53 ms

Operations
------------------------------------------------
Read   : 8 342
Writes : 1
Fetches: 1 316 042
Marks  : 0


Enhanced Info:
+-------------------------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+---------+---------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
|          Table Name           |  Records  |  Indexed  | Non-Indexed | Updates | Deletes | Inserts | Backouts |  Purges  | Expunges |
|                               |   Total   |   reads   |    reads    |         |         |         |          |          |          |
+-------------------------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+---------+---------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
|TABLE2                         |         0 |      4804 |           0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |
|TABLE1                         |         0 |         0 |       96884 |       0 |       0 |       0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |
|TABLE3                         |         0 |    387553 |           0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |
+-------------------------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+---------+---------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
```

And in 2nd case (without dummy condition):

```
Query Time
------------------------------------------------
Prepare       : 16,00 ms
Execute       : 515,00 ms
Avg fetch time: 30,29 ms

Operations
------------------------------------------------
Read   : 7 570
Writes : 1
Fetches: 648 103
Marks  : 0


Enhanced Info:
+-------------------------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+---------+---------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
|          Table Name           |  Records  |  Indexed  | Non-Indexed | Updates | Deletes | Inserts | Backouts |  Purges  | Expunges |
|                               |   Total   |   reads   |    reads    |         |         |         |          |          |          |
+-------------------------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+---------+---------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
|TABLE2                         |         0 |       506 |      152655 |       0 |       0 |       0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |
|TABLE1                         |         0 |       467 |           0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |
|TABLE3                         |         0 |      1885 |           0 |       0 |       0 |       0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |
+-------------------------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+---------+---------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Queries have different execution plans.

```
PLAN JOIN (T2 NATURAL, T1 INDEX (T1_ID_IDX), T3 INDEX (T3_ID_IDX)) 

PLAN JOIN (T1 NATURAL, T3 INDEX (T3_ID_IDX1), T2 INDEX (T2_FK_T1_IDX))
```

It's strange for me. Why query with same sense of conditions works so different? How work FB optimizer and how write quick and optimal queries? How understand this?

P.S. https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/firebird/issues/6941

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why query with same sense of conditions works so different? How work FB optimizer and how write quick and optimal queries? How understand this?

Comment: Unfortunately, the optimizer in Firebird is pretty dumb. The basic recommendation is: don't add dummy conditions. Have you looked at the plan or explained plan of the query?

Comment: Yes, plain in last line have different order: `PLAN JOIN (T2 NATURAL, T1 INDEX (T1_ID_IDX), T3 INDEX (T3_ID_IDX))` vs `PLAN JOIN (T1 NATURAL, T3 INDEX (T3_ID_IDX1), T2 INDEX (T2_FK_T1_IDX))`

Comment: Which Firebird version are you using?

Comment: Both 3.0 and 2.1

Comment: I'd recommend creating a bug report on https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/firebird/issues for Firebird 3.0 (Firebird 2.1 has been out of support for several years now).

Comment: That's good idea :)

Comment: `AND EXISTS` you better not do it in Interbase/Firebird lineup, use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` with `IS NULL` condition instead.

Comment: And those plans were from 2.1 or 3.0 ?

Comment: "And those plans were from 2.1 or 3.0 ?" - both same. And can't do JOINs - there are 1:n (table2 to x-aliased) relations. PS. Thx for editing question.

Comment: @Dżyszla yes you can, just add one more join to the table 2. You can have multiple joins with the same relation by different aliases, why not? or you can even join a table with itself (for exampel for tree-like structures). That is what you have aliases for! `select ... from tableA t1 join tableA t2 on t1.id = t2.id + 1` for example. Same way `select ... from tableA t1 joint tableB t2 on .... join tableC t3 on .... join tableD t4 on .... LEFT OUTER JOIN tableB t5 on t5.id=....  WHERE t5.id IS NULL` - perfectly valid

Comment: I like to get EXISTS, no NOT EXISTS (IS NULL) records, and have relation 1:n - JOIN will multiplicate results records in that case.

Comment: @Dżyszla won't be a multiplicator if you do like `select DISTINCT id from ....` and since you anyway need an index for JOINing the DISTINCT-sorting should be for granted. Then of course without real data would not be ease to make a different select

Comment: ....but personally i would try to make a CTE first joining `table2` onto itself and only then using pre-filtered it with other tables

Comment: But why extra reads thousands of records, when I need check exist any, not all? This is not solution. The performance will be lost again in other place.

Comment: You won't read records any more than you already do for joining and checking `EXISTS`, you would read indexes + selected data rows (MVCC visibility check). But the benefit is predictable single one-direction streamed reading, while `EXISTS` would result in dozens, hunders, thousands queries run again and again, for each row candidate. It usually scales rather badly.

Comment: Not in all cases. When checking exists table is smaller then can be true. Some my case: With `EXISTS`: 1780ms, 479425 reads; with `DISTINCT` and `JOIN`: 2400ms, 880704 reads.